# How do I read structure with strings from binary file (including Linked list)

Tags: c++, string, file, linked-list, binary

My goal is to write and read structure with strings from binary file. **struct Data** is part of singly linked list.

```
    ofstream note;
    ifstream rfrom;

    struct Data
{
    string name;
    string surname;
    int grade;  
};
```

> Here is the **save data** function, that works

```
void SaveData()
    {
        Data* buf_w = new Data;
        size_t NameSz,SurnameSz;
        curr = head;
        
        note.open("Note.bin",ios::trunc | ios::binary);
        while(curr != NULL)
        {
            buf_w->name = curr->data.name;
            NameSz = buf_w->name.size();
            
            buf_w->surname = curr->data.surname;
            SurnameSz = buf_w->surname.size();
            
            buf_w->grade = curr->data.grade;
            
            note.write((char*)&NameSz,sizeof(NameSz));
            note.write((char*)&SurnameSz,sizeof(SurnameSz));
            
            note.write((char*)buf_w,sizeof(Data));
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        note.close();
        delete buf_w;
        cout << "Saved" << endl;
    }
```

> And here is the **read** function that returns error. I think i messed up with resize before I read the data from file, but can't understand how to fix it.

```
void ReadData()
    {
        Data* buf_r = new Data;
        size_t buf_Name, buf_Surname;
        
        rfrom.open("Note.bin",ios::binary);
        
        while(!rfrom.eof())
        {
            if(rfrom.peek()== ios::traits_type::eof()) break;
            
            rfrom.read((char*)&buf_Name,sizeof(buf_Name));
            rfrom.read((char*)&buf_Surname,sizeof(buf_Surname));
            
            buf_r->name.resize(buf_Name);
            buf_r->surname.resize(buf_Surname);
            
            rfrom.read((char*)buf_r,sizeof(Data));
        
            this->AddNode(buf_r->name,buf_r->surname,buf_r->grade);
        }
        rfrom.close();
        delete buf_r;
        cout << "Reading accomplished" << endl;
    }
```

> Linked list code:

```
 class List
{
    private:
        typedef struct node
        {
            Data data;
            
            node* next;
        }* nodePtr;
    
        nodePtr head;
        nodePtr curr;
        nodePtr temp;
            
    public:
        List()
        {
            head = NULL;
            curr = NULL;
            temp = NULL;
        }
        
        
        void AddNode(string NAME,string SURNAME,int GRADE)
        {
            nodePtr n = new node;
            
            n->next = NULL;
            n->data.name = NAME;
            n->data.surname = SURNAME;
            n->data.grade = GRADE;
            
            if (head != NULL)
            {
                curr = head;
                while(curr->next != NULL)
                {
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
                curr->next = n;
            }
            else
            {
                head = n;
            }
        }
        
        void DeleteNode(string delName){
            nodePtr delPtr = NULL;
            temp = head;
            curr = head;
            
            while(curr != NULL && curr->data.name != delName)
            {
                temp = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            
            if(curr == NULL)
            {
                cout << delName << " Not found" << endl;
                cout << "~~~~~~" << endl;
                delete delPtr;
            }
            else
            {
                delPtr = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
                temp->next = curr;
                
                if(delPtr == head)
                {
                    head = head->next;
                    temp = NULL;
                }
                delete delPtr;
                
                cout << "Deleted " << delName << endl;
                cout << "~~~~~~" << endl;
            }
        }
        
        void PrintList()
        {
            curr = head;
            while(curr != NULL)
            {
                cout << curr->data.name << endl<< curr->data.surname << endl << curr->data.grade << endl;
                cout << "~~~~~~" << endl;
                curr = curr->next;
            }   
        }
        
        void SaveData()
        {
            Data* buf_w = new Data;
            size_t NameSz,SurnameSz;
            curr = head;
            
            note.open("Note.bin",ios::trunc | ios::binary);
            while(curr != NULL)
            {
                buf_w->name = curr->data.name;
                NameSz = buf_w->name.size();
                
                buf_w->surname = curr->data.surname;
                SurnameSz = buf_w->surname.size();
                
                buf_w->grade = curr->data.grade;
                
                note.write((char*)&NameSz,sizeof(NameSz));
                note.write((char*)&SurnameSz,sizeof(SurnameSz));
                
                note.write((char*)buf_w,sizeof(Data));
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            note.close();
            delete buf_w;
            cout << "Saved" << endl;
        }
        
        void ReadData()
        {
            Data* buf_r = new Data;
            size_t buf_Name, buf_Surname;
            
            rfrom.open("Note.bin",ios::binary);
            
            while(!rfrom.eof())
            {
                if(rfrom.peek()== ios::traits_type::eof()) break;
                
                rfrom.read((char*)&buf_Name,sizeof(buf_Name));
                rfrom.read((char*)&buf_Surname,sizeof(buf_Surname));
                
                buf_r->name.resize(buf_Name);
                buf_r->surname.resize(buf_Surname);
                
                rfrom.read((char*)buf_r,sizeof(Data));
            
                this->AddNode(buf_r->name,buf_r->surname,buf_r->grade);
            }
            rfrom.close();
            delete buf_r;
            cout << "Reading accomplished" << endl;
        }
};
```

> Main function:

```
   int main()
{       
//########################################  
    List me;
    
    int a;
    cout << "Choice >> ";
    cin >> a;
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
            me.AddNode("AAA","BBB",1);
            me.AddNode("CCC","DDD",2);
            
            me.PrintList();
            me.SaveData();
            break;
            
        case 2:
            me.ReadData();
            me.PrintList();
            break;
            
        case 3:
            note.open("Note.bin",ios::trunc);
            note.close();
            cout << "Cleaned" << endl;
            break;
            
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Haven't worked it out thoroughly yet, but is it a really good idea to write std::string _object_ to a binary file?

Comment: Also, what error does read() return?

Comment: I thought it would be better to avoid arrays of chars, but faced with the problem that string doesn't have constant size. After reading program returns 3221225477

Comment: Is there any way to set string size by hand?

Comment: BTW if i replace string with int for example, reading works with int variables

Comment: You are not storing the text itself by writing a std::string instance to a binary file - only object representation. std::string is merely a pointer to a heap-allocated array of chars and size value stored in the same object. So, when you try to restore your strings with ReadData(), you got a std::string with a pointer leading to non-existent char array (you've called delete on buf_w, remeber?)

Comment: So, you original problem might stem from the reasons I've described above - binary representation of a std::string object usually contains less bytes then average human name.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should write down a length of the string (std::string::length()) followed by an actual string's contents (std::string::data())

Comment: thank's a lot, I'll try it